# Some things are best said in plain language instead of mathematical notation!

Tags: mathematics, knowledge, rebus

Back then in 2013 when I was participating in [International Olympiad in Informatics (IOI)](http://www.ioinformatics.org/index.shtml), I was stumbled on the puzzles on [their newsletters](http://www.ioi2013.org/media/newsletters/). Even until now, I'm pretty clueless for these.

Here are two of them. Could you help me to crack it?

[image: puzzle on newsletter #1]

[image: puzzle on newsletter #2]

Comment: You may have better luck on the Mathematics page if you find that us puzzlers can't solve it :)

Comment: Adding to what @elarr commented above, I strongly recommend you post this on the [***Mathematics Stack Exchange (Math SE)***](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @elarr Don't write us off just yet, we might be on to something :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this can be solved without math knowledge:

("Empodia", 2004) is

> the name of the 4th task of the 2004 IOI

so the solution is probably

> the 4th task of some other IOI?

**Edit**:

I think the second solution could be

> ("Buses", 2008) - the "Buses" task of the 2008 IOI, since the task description matches the mathematical notation... I think. Here is the link to that year's tasks: [IOI2008](http://www.ioinformatics.org/locations/ioi08/contest/IOI2008Booklet1.0.pdf)

Comment: I was just about to comment this! (+1) :D I wasn't sure though, because this puzzle is only related to Empodia by name; the actual task for Empodia that year didn't appear to have anything to do with the mathematical notation that is associated to it here...

Comment: @El-Guest Yeah, I just realized that too :D I'm guessing the notation is equivalent to the written task, in which case we do need mathematical knowledge (big time) to solve this...

Comment: Eutherpy, I think you're more correct than I am...the more I look at Empodia, the more that I'm starting to see similarities between that task and this notation.

Comment: Aah, I see now.. So all of those mathematical notations describe past IOI problems (and we need to find it), and indeed the task description - in plain language - is preferred to be read rather than the notations! Thanks a lot!! :D. Btw I'm accepting this answer as it's the first that hinted the way to solve the puzzle. Also +1 for @ffao's answer for the second puzzle.

Answer (score 5):

The second answer is

> ("Pairs", 2007)

Because the math states:

> Given the dimensionality of the board $a = B$, a max distance $b = D$, and a set of animals $C$, how many pairs of animals can hear each other (that is, what is the size of the set of pairs of animals such that their distance is at most $b $)?

Comment: I think I sort of get what the first one says, but I don't know enough IOI problems to know what they framed it as...

Comment: The one from Croatia, yes! I stumbled upon that one and it caught my eye, but I wasn't sure and decided not to answer :)

Answer (score 2):

To add my two cents to @Eutherpy's answer, in plain language it appears that

> given an integer $k$ and an invertible (apparently on $\mathbb{Z}$) function that maps the large interval $[1,k]$ to itself, we're trying to find the biggest set of intervals where (a) no element appears in more than one interval in the set, and (b) when you apply the function $\pi$ to any element in any interval, the interval remains the same size but shifts up.

An example for k = 5 (not the correct solution) seems to be:

> using the function $\pi(x) = x+1$, where if we *assume* $a<b$ as is common for intervals, we could have the set $\{ [1,2] , [3,4] \}$ be maximal. Facetiously, since there is no $a<b$ restrictiion, the maximal solution would be $\{[1,1] , [2,2], [3,3], [4,4] \}$...but I have no idea on how that relates to the framed intervals from the Empodia problem.